# HTML Text Input not Showing iPad Keyboard

Tags: html, css, ipad, jquery-ui, html-input

So, I have this snippet of HTML:

```
<input id= "email" type= "text" name= "email"/>
```

and this corresponding snippet of CSS:

```
input[type="text"]
{
    /* Padding */
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;

    /* Sizes */
    width: 100%;

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    /* Decoration */
    border: none;
    outline: none;

    /* Shadows */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.8);
}
```

When I tap on the input element, nothing happens. No keyboard is shown in the iPad.

**Edit:** This website is using jQuery, jQuery UI, and jQuery UI Touch.

Comment: tried this URL http://jsfiddle.net/ZcycL/ in simulator - works just fine

Comment: Did you wrap the whole form in a `<form>`-tag with all required attributes? Maybe the white-spaces between = and " generates errors.

Comment: What happens if you test without the CSS settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/issues/detail?id=17

In jQuery UI Touch, in the function

```
function iPadTouchHandler(event) {
```

in the switch/case

```
    switch (event.type) {
        case "touchstart":
```

change

```
            if ($(event.changedTouches[0].target).is("select")) {
```

to

```
            if ($(event.changedTouches[0].target).is("select") || $(event.changedTouches[0].target).is("input")) {
```

to fix the bug.